# Trouble with external monitor under Windows 7 on MacBook Pro Boot Camp

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, macbook, boot-camp, vga

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit on a mid-2010 15" MacBook Pro Intel Core i5 under Boot Camp. I've had trouble getting it to work with my second display and searching Google for an appropriate answer has failed me.

I'm on the latest version of Boot Camp - 3.2 - and have updated the drivers for the NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M.

The monitor is connected via a VGA cable, and is a Dell ST2410.

The monitor is recognised by Windows, which knows it's a Dell and its resolution. The desktop should be extended onto the second monitor - however nothing is showing. It remains black, though it doesn't show a lack of signal coming through which I would have expected.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: What have you tried?...have you tried the simple `Win+P` shortcut to extend display?